# Embedding soundcloud to facebook only returns image and not an iframe

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, soundcloud

Since a few days sharing any souncloud to facebook only returns an image.
Before it shows an iframe.

Posted this bug on facebook and they answered

> This issue is not a bug and is By Design. The issue appears to be on
>   SoundClouds side. From looking at the OG tags on their side they are
>   not specifying a video/audio source so there is no way for us to embed
>   the player

I made a test facebook post https://www.facebook.com/testingcf where you can see the issue

I cannot get the source field from the facebook API so only an imgae will be shown

Comment: I tried severall embeds and it looks like random.

For instance this embed won't work https://soundcloud.com/ahmed-gado-1/sad-piano-violin (only image) but this one works https://soundcloud.com/ahmed-gado-6-1/ne-me-quitte-pas-vero-perez-coco-villanueva (gives an iframe)

Comment: That’s likely an issue soundcloud need to fix on their end.

Comment: Its not an issue at soundcloud, its just greed at Soundcloud as they want more income streams so they disable the facebook player.